# 3D Projection information

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have a 3D scene constructed of many Model3D elements. 

I need to create a 2D layer on top where I want to associate 2D elements with Model3D elements.
How can I calculate the 2D projected bounds of Model3D elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model3D` doesn't have that information as the projection is a property of the view/viewport.

You can use the [`GeneralTransform3DTo2D` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.generaltransform3dto2d.aspx) and specifically the [`TransformBounds` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.generaltransform3dto2d.transformbounds.aspx)

This returns a 2D axis aligned box (`Rect`) from the 3D bounding box supplied. Pass the bounding box of your `Model3D` into this and it will return the projected bounds.

So you can get this transformation the once and use it for each `Model3D` in your scene as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, from what I see I can get GeneralTransform3DTo2D by calling TransformToAncestor of a Visual3D. 
however I'm using Model3D elements. Is there a way to get GeneralTransform3DTo2D for Model3D elements?

Comment: @Oren the transform depends on the view/viewport. The Model3D doesn't know anything about that.

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that I can't instantiate a GeneralTransform3DTo2D ; I need to receive it and I know how to get it for Visual3D elements (TransformToAncestor), not Model3D elements